# Import parent module from submodule

Tags: python, django

I'm having an import error I don't understand, and haven't been able to find a solution in other SO questions:

I have this django structure:

- project_root/

  - apps/

    - __init__.py
    - my_app/

      - __init__.py
      - models.py
      - views.py
      - reports/

        - __init__.py
        - R1.py
        - R2.py

In either of R1.py or R2.py the statement

```
from apps.my_app.models import MyModel
```

throws an ImportError. I know MyModel exists... I import it exactly the same way in views.py.

In apps.my_app.reports.__init__.py I have the lines:

```
from R1 import R1_Report
from R2 import R2_Report
```

since RX_Report classes are defined in each of those files.

That's all the potentially relevant info I can think of... any ideas?

Comment: May be you are victim of [circular import](http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm) have you imported somthing from R1.py or from R2.py into apps.my_app.models also??

Comment: Oops! You were right. I didn't see your comment until I posted my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh... nevermind. It was a circular import. Solved it by switching

```
from apps.my_app import reports
...
reports.stuff()
```

to

```
import apps.my_app
...
apps.my_app.reports.stuff()
```

in models.py